# How is the current element of an iteration related to the iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Consider the following code:

```
mylist = [
    {'a': 1},
    {'b': 2},
]

for el in mylist:
    print(mylist)
    x, y = el.popitem()
    print(x, y)
```

I expected `mylist` not to change over the iteration (so when printing it it would be the same every time), because why should it since I am working on a variable which is the current iterated element.

The output is

```
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
a 1
[{}, {'b': 2}]
b 2
```

This means that popping the current value of the iteration impacts the iterator itself. Why is it so? (I guess this is because the current element is a pointer to the element in the list)

How should I iterate so that the iterated list does not change? (I need to `popitem()` the current element to gather its key and value)

Comment: Just for your edification `mydict` is actually a `list`

Comment: The variable `el` is a name for the object in the list (`mydict` is a confusing name).

Comment: @That1Guy:OK, I changed the name - I had initially another idea for the example

Comment: @PeterWood: OK, I changed the name - I had initially another idea for the example

Comment: What's the expected output here? you can just do `for el in mylist: for key, value in el.items()`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: it is less the expected output on iyts own that the fact that manipulating the current element changes the source list

Comment: I don't understand your comment sorry, can you add the expected output to the question

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: OK, I further specified what is expected form `mylist` in the question

Comment: A concrete output like you showed in the last code block is more helpful rather than a textual description

Comment: I'm not sure why this is unexpected. Your list object contains dict objects. You then iterate over those dict objects, and then *mutate them*, thus, this change will be reflected in the list, becaues that's what the list contains, *those objects*

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the `el` variable is a reference to the values in the list.

You can use `.items()` to get the key-value pairs from the dictionaries

```py
mydict = [
    {'a': 1},
    {'b': 2},
]

for el in mydict:
    print(mydict)
    x, y = list(el.items())[0] # This assumes that you only have 1 pair in the list, otherwise it will return the first one
    print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `popitem`, you're modifying the element (dict) in place, so when you print the second time, it is empty.

```
mylist = [
    {'a': 1},
    {'b': 2},
]

for el in mylist:
    print(mylist) # First iteration:  [{'a':1},{'b':2}]
                  # Second iteration: [{},{'b':2}] because the first iteration removed el ({'a':1})
    x, y = el.popitem() # Remove the items from the dict el
    print(x, y)
```

`el` is just a pointer to the element so if you modify it, it's modified in the containing list.

You can always use the [`items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method of `dict`:

```
for el in mylist:
    print(mylist)
    #x, y = el.items()[0] # Python 2
    x, y = list(el.items())[0] # Python 3
    print(x, y)
```

`items` returns the key,value pairs as a list of tuples *without removing* them from the dictionary.